# EKS ingress-nginx and NLB with https redirect

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-eks, aws-nlb, ingress-nginx

I'm having issues with the nlb lately, it was quite an adventure to have nlb with https termination on the lb working with a redirection http=>https and an ingress-nginx on EKS.

Now, I want to have the X-Forwarded headers passed to the pod, but that breaks the http=>https redirection, I get a 400 on http requests.

On the service, I tried to put the service with http or tcp protocol, same thing.

Adding the `service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-proxy-protocol: "*"` header to the service, activates the proxy protocol v2 on all targets, and activating `use-proxy-protocol: 'true'` in the configmap for nginx breaks the http-snippet with the 308 redirection:

```
http-snippet: |
    server {
      listen 2443;
      return 308 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
```

Does anyone has a way to make it so that it can use the nlb with all the good header and the redirect working?

**EDIT** at comment request adding full working config

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 0.41.0
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
  name: ingress-nginx-controller
data:
  http-snippet: |
    server {
      listen 2443 proxy_protocol;
      return 308 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
  proxy-real-ip-cidr: 10.4.0.0/16
  use-forwarded-headers: 'true'
  use-proxy-protocol: 'true'
  compute-full-forwarded-for: 'true'
```

Comment: Where did you get `ingress-nginx` from? https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/ ? If so then to enable HTTPS redirect you only have to configure TLS in an Ingress resource: https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#server-side-https-enforcement-through-redirect

Comment: Please read the title, I'm specifically asking in the use case where you have an NLB not a CLB or ALB.

Comment: I've read it again and I still don't get why do you use that http-snippet for redirects when nginx do that automatically if TLS configured in an ingress resource. I use NLB and nginx ingress in production myself and I didn't have to do a thing to get what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Hooo I see the problem here... I edited the post.

Comment: I want the ssl termination on the lb not on the pod.

Comment: I see now. Hope this will help you https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/73297#issuecomment-601787548

Comment: The ssl part is working, the issue is that the http=>https redirect is broken when trying to have the header passed to the pod.

Comment: Looking at the official guide (https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/load-balancer/using-proxy-protocol/#configuring-nginx-to-accept-the-proxy-protocol) it seems `listen` directive should contain `proxy_protocol` for NGINX to accepts proxy protocol headers. Could you try changing `listen 2443;` for `listen 2443 proxy_protocol;`?

Comment: @anemyte That's it... It's obvious but I thought that it was doing it was doing it as long as you activated it in the configmap... You can put that in an answer and I will validate :)

Comment: @night-gold mind sharing the full working example? it will be super useful for us

Comment: @AmitBaranes I edited the question with the full configmap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To conclude our comment discussion with @night-gold, to make NGINX to accept proxy protocol you have to specifically mention that in listen directive:

```
http {
    #...
    server {
        listen 80   proxy_protocol;
        listen 443  ssl proxy_protocol;
        #...
    }
}
```

Check out [NGINX guide](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/load-balancer/using-proxy-protocol/) for more.

Comment: Just a little precision, the directive is activated in the configmap using use-proxy-protocol: 'true' to have it globally. But it's not taken into account inside the http-snippet of the configmap.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I tried to use that config with the HTTP snippet. But it didn't work. So searching about it a find the PR that solves the redirect with that config. The PR also exposes to the solution Port 2443 with the configuration `tohttps` in order to make the redirect work. I based on that one and work it for me.

https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/pull/5374

https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/pull/5374/files#diff-885b46a1b162f530aa95239e8c3adf9887a4ce863b443f49f06368011a4259ddR390-R393

Answer (score -1):

In addition to this answer don't forget to add annotation of Proxy Protocol to service.

https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-load-balancer-controller/v2.2/guide/service/nlb/#protocols

Here is my values in helm chart

```
helm upgrade \
      ingress-nginx ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx \
      --namespace ingress-nginx \
      --set controller.service.type=LoadBalancer \
      --set controller.service.annotations."service\.beta\.kubernetes\.io/aws-load-balancer-type"=nlb \
      --set controller.service.annotations."service\.beta\.kubernetes\.io/aws-load-balancer-nlb-target-type"=ip \
      --set controller.service.annotations."service\.beta\.kubernetes\.io/aws-load-balancer-cross-zone-load-balancing-enabled"=true \
      --set controller.service.annotations."service\.beta\.kubernetes\.io/aws-load-balancer-type"=external \
      --set controller.service.annotations."service\.beta\.kubernetes\.io/aws-load-balancer-name"="nginx-ingress" \
      --set controller.service.annotations."service\.beta\.kubernetes\.io/aws-load-balancer-proxy-protocol"="*" \
      --set controller.service.annotations."service\.beta\.kubernetes\.io/aws-load-balancer-scheme"="internet-facing" \
      --set controller.config."proxy-real-ip-cidr"="xx.xx.xx.xx/xx" \
      --set controller.config."use-forwarded-headers"="true" \
      --set controller.config."use-proxy-protocol"="true" \
      --set controller.config."compute-full-forwarded-for"="true" \
      --set controller.config."http-snippet"="
server{
  listen 2443;
  return 308 https://\$host\$request_uri;
}" \
      --dry-run
```

Comment: Helm conf is irrelevant in this case, please see question and you can see that I put the conf lines (not helm)